# Persistent IsExpanded on ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm currently using WPF and data bindings to display/update data. I have a TreeView and an ItemTemplate.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{StaticResource Labels}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Key}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </TreeViewItem>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

"Labels" is a Dictionary that I assigned before "InitializeComponent". The problem is that every time I change the data and call "Refresh" on the TreeView, all of the tree view items go back to a collapsed state even if they were expanded.

How do I keep expanded items in their expanded state?

EDIT: For others trying to do this, I'm just going to put the XAML that worked for me (since I had a hard time finding it when I was looking online). I made a helper class that kept IsExpanded as part of the data source.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{StaticResource Labels}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Key}"
                              IsExpanded="{Binding Path=Value.IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.RealValue}" />
                </TreeViewItem>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create wrapper class called 'Expandable' which wraps your value and exposes a property IsExpanded. Then bind the TreeViewItems IsExpanded value to the Expandable's IsExpanded Property in two way binding mode to store the State.
This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating style for the TreeViewItem and set the binding mode to two way.